# SQL Syntax check

Tags: sql, sum, between, having

I want to know if this SQL query is correct:

```
Select t
from S
having sum(S.r) between 0 AND 10000
```

My question is about the Having sum() Between X and Y
Is that correct?

Comment: you can answer you own question if you have try executing it.

Comment: You can test these things easily using tools such as http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

you lack `GROUP BY` clause

```
Select t
from S
GROUP BY t
having sum(S.r) between 0 AND 10000
```